# filter an object with sub arrays

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi i'm trying to filter this object to get the following object result. Some Object might have only one sub number in the sub Array. I have added a sample and a needed result.

```
//Curently have 
Object {
"contactType": "person",
"firstName": "Jame Bond",
 "id": "05434909-468F-4AF4-wfde-000000000:ABPerson",
"imageAvailable": false,
 "key": undefined,
"name": "Jame Bond",
 "phoneNumbers": Array [
  Object {
   "countryCode": "us",
    "digits": "+14255556668",
    "id": "53109855-4BA3-4A29-A65C-05B60ED299FA",
    "label": "‎old number",
    "number": "+1 (424) 555-0000",
  },
 Object {
    "countryCode": "gb",
  "digits": "+44712345678",
    "id": "37D77251-39E3-488D-9832-102E7B907E24",
     "label": "mobile",
    "number": "+44712345678",
   },
],
},

//need 
Object {
"name": "James Bond"
  Object {
"digits1": "+14255556668",
"digits2": "+44712345678" // if exists! 
  }
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: have you tried destructuring? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
const { 
  name, 
  phoneNumbers: [ 
    // ':' equals as, and '=' means default value, when prop doesn't exist
    // could be anything you want
    { digits: digits1 }, 
    { digits: digits2 = null } 
  ],
} = yourObject;
const newObject = { name, { digits1, ...digits2 } };
```

We are simply destructuring object and create new one from that variables. You can find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

If phone numbers may very, I would suggest the following code.

```
const { name, phoneNumbers } = yourObject;
const allDigits = phoneNumbers.map(({ digits }, i) => ({[`digits${i}`]: digits}));
const newObject = Object.assign({ name }, ...allDigits);
```

Comment: I don't think that will work if there is only one item in the phone numbers.

Comment: Sample provided has two numbers. If there are dynamic requirements, answer can surely be adopted accordingly.

Comment: That is true, however it does say in the desired outcome that the second number may not exist. Can you show the solution how to handle that?

Comment: @Andrew no problem. You just need to spread that variable, if it's null, it won't show up in the created object. I edited the answer.

Comment: @Andrew also added dynamic version.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for that comment haven't noticed at first